# What is a force multipole?

Tags: classical-mechanics, dipole, multipole-expansion, spherical-harmonics

In a recent talk about physics and mechanics inside the cell, I heard such terms as 'force monopole' and 'force dipole'. What do such terms mean?

Are they talking about the angular distributions, viz. the $\ell=0,1,...$ modes of the spherical harmonics? If so, then what would a force monopole, dipole, etc. look like?

Any references on this topic? A simple search did not turn up anything.

Comment: I would assume they mean the decomposition of the force field into [vector spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics). The force monopole is the constant part, the force dipole would tend to stretch or compress along an axis, and so on.

Comment: That sounds close to what they were implying. I read the Wikipedia article, but could you please elucidate more the physical significance of each term? Perhaps with examples. Also, do you have any references?